# Can I get unknown type from SQL query in asp.net mvc?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

Do we have to use type in SQL query in ASP.NET MVC ?

I want to get a result that has no type defined before. Let's say:

```
select TABLE1.X, TABLE2.Y from TABLE1,TABLE2
```

How can I get this query's result? There are classes for `TABLE1` and `TABLE2`, but none for result. Is it necessary that I construct an object that fit for the result?

Comment: It depends on what you wish to do with the result. Can you provide a bit more context to your question? You could store it into a Tuple to return for example. Are you using any ORM or plain SQL queries with datareaders?

Comment: i will only use select statements. all kind of selects. i use EF with razor. i just want to get the result and show in a webgrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `DataReader` you can use each field as you want.

```
DataTable dt;
using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
  dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Load(dr);
}
```

And you don't have to create any object.

Comment: Yes but i just gave an example. The query will be dynamic. what i want is something like this: i will have a textbox. and user write down a query here. and i will show the result to the user. something like that.

Comment: Beside the danger that represent, I think you can expose the results in a datatable

Comment: yeah kind of. If there is a way.

Comment: @user1844920 I see a huge security issue here. Also update your question with the context. Concretely you wish to execute dynamicly given text queries inputted by the user and represent the result to the user. (Sort of web backend to the database). Then you're fairly forced to fall back to plain ADO.NET and the code Diego gave you should help.

Comment: I am aware of this security issue. When i say user, i mean the people also have access to database that we use. the code that Diego gave, i will try it. is sure it will work. thanks a lot both of you.